# Ignore HTML injected by user but rendering developer's html - Angular

Tags: html, angular

I want to create a Terms and Conditions component in Angular which will be retrieved from a DB. The T&C will include html and user data (user's company). The reason I include html in T&C because I want to be variable and I will change the text as well as the layout in the future.

If I have the following T&C:

```
<p>The company USERCOMPANY will have the responsibility to accept the T&C</p>
```

*where the USERCOMPANY will be replaced by user's company

What solution is in Angular and HTML so that it will render my html tags (in thus case p tags) but without rendering the user input in case he adds something like: `<strong>My Company</strong>` or js script?

Comment: That's not really the purpose of Angular, you should rather store the T&C only, and no HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have both stored seperately you can escape the value in USERCOMPANY using (quick and dirty):

```
USERCOMPANYstring.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/"/g, "&quot;").replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
```

Include your escaped usercompany string into your other html code using some kind of replacement and then put that in your html using a `safe` pipe:
`<p [innerHTML]="yourVariable | safe: html"></p>`

Safe Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import {
  DomSanitizer,
  SafeHtml,
  SafeStyle,
  SafeScript,
  SafeUrl,
  SafeResourceUrl
} from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Pipe({
  name: "safe"
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  public transform(
    value: any,
    type: string
  ): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
    switch (type) {
      case "html":
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
      case "style":
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
      case "script":
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
      case "url":
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
      case "resourceUrl":
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
      default:
        throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
    }
  }
}
```

This will sanitize your input coming from the database and the escaped characters (i.e. USERCOMPANY) shouldn't appear as html, but the rest would be normal html and trusted by Angular since you sanitized it.